# Custom android notification icon not showing on Garmin watch

Tags: android, android-push-notification, garmin

In Android Studio I added *Image Asset* to *res* folder. Icon Type is Notification Icons. In AndroidManifest I added

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_name" />
```

On phones my icon is showing up as expected. But on Garmin watch (mine is Venu Sq2) icon is not showing up, instead just default message bubble icon.

Some apps like Gmail, Instagram has their own icon showing up on my watch notification and some other app notifications are not being shown like my app.

How to fix it?